# Can box-shadow effect be applied to just left & right sides of a div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get a box shadow applied to only the left & right sides of a div?

```
box-shadow: 0px 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
```

I tried changing this to a few varients of:

```
box-shadow: 0, foo, 0, foo;
```

but that didn't work well.

In the image below, I want to remove the bottom line (and the top one, but you can't see that in this image).

I would prefer not to use an image if possible.

[image: Div with a box-shadow]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the box-shadow on :before and :after

```
div:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
}
div:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qq5tQ/

Comment: that just turns out to be a messy solution and does not look well cross browser

Comment: Messy how? It works fine in IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. If you are rude to people who respond to your questions, nobody is going to want to help you.

Comment: I appologise if I sounded rude but I used the code exactly as you have it and its not suitable. The left shadow shows fine, the right shadow is offline, positioned below the container. http://jsfiddle.net/QpHu7/ Anyways I decided not to find a fix for it and did something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the way to do it is to use another box shadow on top of it so you css would look like this:

```
box-shadow: 0px -45px white,0px 22px white, 2px 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4)
```

Comment: this adds white above the div which overlays ontop of my navagation menu.  Not a useful tip.

Comment: Just to reiterate, not a useful tip for my current situation... Could be useful for others though :)